# How do I create the content of type multipart/form-data using c# as part of my response to Get request

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

I have to populate the content object present inside HttpResponseMessage which the content-type  = multipart/form-data .
I want to send a file and a string in the response content.

Comment: Do you have an example of your controller and view? (I'm assuming it's MVC). You have to define the content type of the form in the view.

Answer (score 0):

in the view the form tag should be something like:-

```
<form id="formContent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="controller/actionMethod">
```

and the file upload components should be like:-

```
<input type="file" id="file1Upload" size="50" name="files" />
<input type="file" id="file2Upload" size="50" name="files" />
```

in the controller, the signature should be like this:-

```
public string actionMethod(object model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{

foreach (var file in files)
{
  //write here what do you want to do with each file
}
 ....
}
```

notice `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` is just added in the signature

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response but the scenario is not where the server is excepting a resquest of enctype = "multipart/formdata". I already have a file in the server which I want to send across with content of the response along with another string variable value.